# GoLang Unmarshal JSON From Elastic Search Result

Tags: elasticsearch, go, go-gin

I have data returned from Elasticsearch, using "github.com/olivere/elastic". That sort of works, when i add it to my struct and string it, like so,

```
data := Api {
    Total: myTotal,
    Data: string(result),
}

c.JSON(http.StatusOK, totalData)
```

the api is a struct like so,

```
type Api struct {
   Total interface{}
   Data interface{} 
}
```

This returns data ok, from 1 to any number of results on request. How the results loaded into the data interface are not escaped or something, e.g.

```
"Data":"{\"CID\":\"XXXXXXXXXX\",\"Link\":\"XXXXXXXXX\",
```

So I have tried to unmarshal the data before adding it to the api struct.

```
var p DataApi

err := json.Unmarshal(result, &p)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

totalData := Api {
    Total: myTotal,
    Data: p,
}

c.JSON(http.StatusOK, totalData)
```

This sort of works fine, returns the data in the correct way, but only when loading one result. When 2 or more results are requested, I get this error from the unmarshal panic

```
invalid character '{' after top-level value
```

I have tried and google all over but can not find a solution to this? I am not sure what I am doing wrong? The DataApi is a nested set of structs, I was not sure if there was anything I should be being because of that?

This is being run within the Gin framework.

Thanks.

EDIT

So when I use `fmt.Println` on the string(result) I can print any number of results on the screen. How can I add this to the API struct and then I need the struct converted into JSON data. Is there some way of appending this string data on the JSON converted API struct?

Comment: can you provide an example of what `string(result)` looks like with 1 and multiple results?

Comment: It is what it should be, {"CID":"XXXXXXXXXX","Link":"XXXXXXXXX",} etc

Answer (score 0):

Try to unmarshal multiple results into a slice:

```
var q []Api
err = json.Unmarshal(result, &q)
```

See on playground https://play.golang.org/p/D_bVAd4jBlI

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Api struct {
    Total interface{}
    Data  interface{}
}

func main() {

    data := Api{
        Total: 1,
        Data:  "2",
    }

    result, err := json.Marshal(data)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("single data: %s\n", result)

    var p Api
    err = json.Unmarshal(result, &p)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    dataSlice := []Api{data}

    result, err = json.Marshal(dataSlice)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("slice of data: %s\n", result)

    var q []Api
    err = json.Unmarshal(result, &q)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tried this and I get the same error, invalid character '{' after top-level value

Comment: @Coder99 Did you try to run the example on the playground https://play.golang.org/p/D_bVAd4jBlI ?

Comment: I will do, sorry been busy all day, looking into it in more detail now. Thanks

Comment: I am very new to go but dont see how this will help me, I have tried it with my data and still get the same error. I have updated the question

Comment: @Coder99 Can you edit the example on the playground to provide a runnable code showing exactly how it is failing for you?

Answer (score 0):

Use [json.RawMessage](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage) to store arbitrary JSON documents:

```
var p json.RawMessage

err := json.Unmarshal(result, &p)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

totalData := Api {
    Total: myTotal,
    Data: p,
}

c.JSON(http.StatusOK, totalData)
```

Comment: Just give this ago and still get the same error,  invalid character '{' after top-level value

Comment: This suggests that you are trying to Unmarshal multiple concatenated JSON documents. Use a json.Decoder instead: https://play.golang.org/p/85WPi0NxYrT

Answer (score 0):

I have a working solution to my problem, I just use the Hits Hits From the data returned by elastic search, I would like just the source data but i think it does what I need it to do... for now.

Thanks.